# Beautiful Soup Nested Tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am struggling with how to get to a nested table within this URL:

view-source:http://taxweb.co.guilford.nc.us/CamaPublicAccess/PropertySummary.aspx?REID=0180721

Specifically the data stored for "Owner's Mailing Address" where the new table starts on line 370

```
owner_fields = soup.find(text="Owner's Mailing Address").find('table'),
owner_address = owner_fields.find('td').get_text(),
owner_city = owner_fields.find('td')[2].get_text(),
owner_state_zip = owner_fields.find('td')[3].get_text(),
```

Am I way off here?

Answer (score 1):

`soup.findAll(attrs={"id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_table3"})[0]` locates and returns the table.

The additional `.findAll('b')` locates the container and content of the address elements.

The `map()` statement goes over the `.findAll('b')` elements and returns a unicode version of their content.

```
address_contents = map(lambda value: value.contents, soup.findAll(attrs={"id":"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_table3"})[0].findAll('b'))

In [56]: address_contents 
Out[56]: 
 [[u'101 OAKHURST AVE'],
 [u'&nbsp;'],
 [u'HIGH POINT'],
 [u'\n', <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DetailsView4_Label1"></span>],
 [u'NC'],
 [u'27262']]
```

I will leave the assignment of the list values up to you.